# DBIx::Class - best way to add support for 'FOR UPDATE NOWAIT'

Tags: perl, oracle, dbix-class

I want to add support for "FOR UPDATE NOWAIT" to select statements with `->select(..., { for => 'update_nowait' })` (for Oracle).

I'm using [DBIx::Class 0.08127](https://metacpan.org/module/ABRAXXA/DBIx-Class-0.08127/lib/DBIx/Class.pm)

I can modify DBIx/Class/SQLMaker/Oracle.pm, but I was wondering if there is another (preferred) way, especially if it doesn't involve modifying distribution files.

Comment: If you know how to fix it by altering the distribution, why not submit a patch? I'm sure it would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `DBix::Class::SQLMaker::Oracle` is the way I've done it.

Just include your modified module in a directory that occurs before the directory containing the DBIx Class distribution in `@INC`.

The modification to DBIx/Class/SQLMaker/Oracle.pm is to add these lines:

```
my $for_syntax = {
  update => 'FOR UPDATE',
  shared => 'FOR SHARE',
  update_nowait => 'FOR UDPATE NOWAIT',
};

sub _lock_select {
  my ($self, $type) = @_;
  my $sql = $for_syntax->{$type} || croak "Unknown SELECT ... FOR type '$type' requested";
  return " $sql";
}
```

Now if `$for_syntax` were a method call instead of a lexical you wouldn't have to repeat the definition of `_lock_select`. Something to consider if you want to submit a patch.